# Angular 5.2 AOT build error Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 when using $event

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I am capturing output event in method without parameter and it's working fine. but when i try to build AOT --prod getting folloing error.

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

```
Html code: SaveSortOrder($event)
backend code: SaveSortOrder() {}
```

Answer (score 31):

AOT is very strict.  In this case you are passing the value of `$event` when you call `SaveSortOrder`, but the method doesn't accept one.  Either change the html not to pass `$event` or add an argument to SaveSortOrder.

Do one of the following:

**Html code**

`<button click="SaveSortOrder()" />`

**backend**

`SaveSortOrder($event: any) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

In the local environment, it doesn't give an error but on the live environment, it gives error so to solve that perform any one of the following fix.

**Reason**
You pas a parameter from HTML but doesn't have a variable in typescript method

**Component Html Fix**

OR

**Component ts file Fix**
SaveSortOrder($event: any) {  }

Answer (score 0):

The html send a parameter to his function in typescript that not excepeted or vice versa.
Html Code

```
<div (click)="closeSideInfo($event)">
```

TypeScript

```
 closeSideInfo() {}
```

Then, remove a parameter in html or adding it to function in typescript